# VBA - remove duplicates (Case NOT sensitive) separated by a comma inside cells in excel?

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I have a vba that remove duplicates separated by a comma inside cells in excel, I want it to be case NOT sensitive. Any ideas??

Now it works like this (words with different case considered NOT the same):
Hello, hello, hi, hi ---> Hello, hello, hi

I want it to work like this (words with different case considered SAME):
Hello, hello, hi, hi ---> Hello, hi
OR
Hello, hello, hi, hi ---> hello, hi

End result can be any case except ALL CAPITAL.
So,"hello"/"Hello" will work!

```
Sub DeleteDuplicateTags()
Dim c, arr, el, data, it
Dim start As Date
Dim targetRange As Range

Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set targetRange = Range("A1:A2000")

data = targetRange

start = Now
For i = LBound(data) To UBound(data)
    For j = LBound(data, 2) To UBound(data, 2)
        c = data(i, j)
        dict.RemoveAll
        arr = Split(c, ",")
        For Each el In arr
            On Error Resume Next
            dict.Add Trim(el), Trim(el)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next
        c = ""
        For Each it In dict.Items
           c = c & it & ","
        Next
        If c <> "" Then c = Left(c, Len(c) - 1)
        data(i, j) = c
    Next j
Next i
targetRange = data
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Working time: " & Format(Now - start, "hh:nn:ss")

End Sub
```

Thanks!! Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: Would you like the results to keep their original case or would it be okay if they're all converted to lower case as well?

Comment: Hello! Any case work for me, except ALL CAPITAL. 
It's definitely OK if they're all converted to lower case :)
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: before your for loop add the line `dict.comparemode = vbTextCompare` and then the case does not matter :)

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help!